# Contacts list and Chat Box suddenly disappeared from the lefthand side of Gmail account

Tags: gmail, google-talk

Even though chat is on, I can’t see my chat list. Can you please tell me how can I get back?

Answer (score 1):

Click on the bubble icon at the bottom of the page, right under where the chat list should be.

[image]

Comment: Is that a special theme you have?

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra It’s the “Tree” classic theme, but the bubble has nothing to do with it—you simply can hide the chat now.

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra It’s a square bubble, not a building. :) And no, it’s pointed correctly—the dots show/hide a second gadget, while the bubble shows/hides the chat, whether there is a different gadget installed or not.

Comment: Are you responding to a deleted comment?

Comment: Yes, there was a comment about a building, or something.